# Order in which code is executed with UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have an issue with my code which exemplified by a simplified version below. I expect for "2" to be printed before "1". However, that is not the case.

Does this have something to do with the fact that the code doesn't actually run from top to bottom?

```
if moveConclusion.patternDetected == true {
    for i in 0...8 {
        if pressedArray[i] {
            self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations:{
                self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.correctColour
                //self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / -12)
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations:{
                    self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    // self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 12)
                    print("2")
                })
            })
        }
    }
    print("1")
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   2
>   2
>   ...

Comment: `animate` run asynchronously. 0.1 second is an long time in terms of CPU time so `print(1)` is executed before the completion handle of `animate` can finish

Comment: The first animation won't even begin until the next runloop and that is long after the `for` loop has completed.

Comment: Also, may be good to point out that Apple is discouraging the use of block-based animations. Check out the Animating Views with Block Objects section on the UIView documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

I have started switching over to UIViewPropertyAnimator class (as suggested) and have found it great to tackling timing / threading issues with its API. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `UIView.animate` *orders* the animation; it does not *perform* it. The animation engine will perform it — later. You are handing to the animation engine two blocks to be executed *later*, meaning *after* all your code comes to an end (to be technical, it's when the next screen refresh frame comes along and the current CATransaction is committed):

- The `animations` block will run after all your code has finished and it's time for the animation to *start*.
- The `completion` block will run after the animation *ends* (that's what "completion" means).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `print("2")` executes approximately 0.1-0.2 seconds after this code starts, but `print("1")` happens after the for loop executes.

The animations do not execute synchronously with the for loop. The `print("2")` will happen during the second animation, but by that time, the for loop has completed and `print("1")` has executed.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView.animate` runs on the main thread and is asynchronous. So as soon as that code is called it dispatches it onto the NEXT runloop, (which is after the this function terminates, which means after the entire for loop).

In other words, the `UIView.animate` call essentially just queues it for the next run loop. And the `print("1")` statement still occurs on the current run loop.

Then the animation block is run, and once the animation block finishes, the completion block runs. So the print for the 2 comes WAAAAAY later in terms of CPU processing, and is definitely the expected behavior.